# Conjectured Value of Ramsey Number $R(3,10)$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, ramsey-theory

It is [known](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1) that the value of the Ramsey number $R(3,10)$ is either 40, 41, or 42. Have any experts in the field offered a conjecture as to which it might be?

Comment: Everyone knows the answer is 42.

Comment: I doubt there is anything in writing. The person to contact is probably [Radziszowski](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~spr/homepage.html), whose computer searches (usually spanning years) are responsible for several of the most recent known values.